# Strong convexity of quadratic functional $x\mapsto \|Ax-b\|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $m,n\in\mathbb N$, $A\in\mathscr L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$, $b\in\mathbb R^m$ and define 
$$f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R,\quad x\mapsto \|Ax-b\|^2 $$
We're supposed to determine when this mapping is strongly convex. I think we can omit the translation and simply study $x\mapsto \|Ax\|^2$, instead.  So, suppose it is strongly convex, we then start calculating..
$$\lambda \|Ax\|^2 + (1-\lambda)\|Ay\|^2 -\|\lambda Ax + (1-\lambda)Ay\|^2\\
=\lambda\|Ax\|^2 +(1-\lambda)\|Ay\|^2 - \left (\lambda ^2\|Ax\|^2 + (1-\lambda)\|Ay\|^2 + 2\lambda (1-\lambda)\langle Ax,Ay\rangle\right ) \\
= \lambda (1-\lambda ) \left ( \|Ax\|^2 + \|Ay\|^2 - 2\langle Ax,Ay \rangle\right ) = \lambda (1-\lambda )\|Ax-Ay\|^2 \overset{?}\geq \delta ^2\lambda(1-\lambda)\|x-y\|^2,$$

where $\delta >0$ is a fixed constant. For strong convexity it would then suffice that for every $x\in\mathbb R^n$
$$\|Ax\| \geq \delta\|x\| \implies \|A\|\geq \left\| A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\| \geq \delta.$$
At this point I'm confused. Are we done or can we specify how operator norm is controlled? Can we pick for every operator $A$ the constant $\delta>0$ such that strong convexity demand is satisfied?

Comment: Is $A$ injective?

Comment: @copper.hat It is arbitrary, perhaps there are necessary conditions for $A$

Comment: As an extreme case, if $A=0$ then $f$ is constant and definitely not strongly convex. If $A$ is injective, then $A^TA$ is positive definite and you can use this to show strong convexity.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read everything you have above. $A$ is injective **iff** there is some $\delta >0$ such that $\|Ax\| \ge \delta \|x\|$.

Comment: @copper.hat ah yes, good catch !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is twice continuously differentiable. So $f$ is strongly convex if and only if the Hessian matrix $\nabla^2 f(x) \succ 0$ is positive definite for all $x$. You can compute the Hessian $\nabla^2 f(x) = 2A^TA$. It implies $f$ is strongly convex if $\text{Null}(A) = \{0\}$. So $A$ must be injective.

Comment: $F(x) = e^x$, $F''(x) > 0$ but it is not strongly convex. 2-D case: $F(x,y) = e^x + e^y$, $\nabla^2 F(x)$ is positive definite, but it is not strongly convex.